# Integrate $ \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} (\pi^2-x^2)\sin nx \ dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider the function $f:(-\pi,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $x \mapsto (\pi+x)(\pi-x)$

Compute the fourier series of $f$

So far, I've worked out $a_o$ by:
\begin{equation}
a_o = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} (\pi^2-x^2) \ dx 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 =\frac{4}{3}\pi^2
\end{equation}

And I got stuck working out $a_n$
\begin{equation}
 \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} (\pi^2-x^2)\cos nx \ dx
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 = \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \left\lbrace \left[ (\pi^2-x^2) \frac{1}{n} \sin nx\right]^\pi_{-\pi} - \frac{1}{n} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} (\pi^2-x^2)\sin nx  \ \right \rbrace dx 
\end{equation}

I'm stuck on integrating the $ \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} (\pi^2-x^2)\sin nx \ dx$ par

Comment: For sine function is odd. For cosine use generalized rule for integration by parts. Where $u=\pi^2 - x^2$ and $v=\cos nx$ Here you will essentially keep on integrating v and differentiating u until u becomes 0 and series terminate.

Comment: How would you know if a function is odd or even?

Comment: Odd functions $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and sine behaves like this. Even functions $f(-x)=f(x)$

Comment: There is an error in your partial integration.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x) = (\pi^2-x^2)\sin(nx)$ is an odd function, i.e., we have $f(-x) = -f(x)$. Hence,
$$\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

a quick answer, hope this helps:

using integration by parts you obtain:
\begin{align}
\int x^2\sin(nx)dx&=\frac{2x\sin nx}{n^2}-\frac{(n^2x^2-2)\cos nx}{n^3}\\
\int x^2\cos(nx)dx&=\frac{2x\cos nx}{n^2}+\frac{(n^2x^2-2)\sin nx}{n^3}\\
\end{align}

Comment: That's not necessary, since the integral of an odd function over $[-\pi,\pi]$ is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that is right. just added a bit more ...